# Agora Black screen in Flutter didn't open the camera?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, agora.io, flutter-android

I'm trying to make an video calling app using Agora
But  Camera didn't open it shows a black screen
I tried several ways but it doesn't work.
My appid and temptoken are updated(I make it under the 24 hours)
Add the Androidmainfist.xml are added in the plug in docs
Still I get the blackscreen

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:agora_uikit/agora_uikit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class VideoCalll extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoCalll({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoCalll> createState() => _VideoCalllState();
}

class _VideoCalllState extends State<VideoCalll> {
  late final AgoraClient _client;
  late bool _loading = true;
  String tempToken = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    getToken();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getToken() async {
    String link =
        "https://agora-node-tokenserver.kumaresanjackie.repl.co/access_token?channelName=demoproject";

    Response _response = await get(Uri.parse(link));
    Map data = jsonDecode(_response.body);
    setState(() {
      tempToken = data["token"];
    });
    // late final AgoraClient
    _client = AgoraClient(
        agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
          appId: "4b463a1f8d3448928f4450c9be2db3ba",
          channelName: 'demoproject',
          tempToken: data["token"],
        ),
        enabledPermission: [Permission.camera, Permission.microphone]);

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2))
        .then((value) => setState(() => _loading = false));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _loading
        ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  AgoraVideoViewer(
                    client: _client,
                  ),
                  AgoraVideoButtons(client: _client),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please attach the Agora SDK logs to the issue. Also, instead of generating the token yourself, you can simply pass the URL to the `tokenUrl` method inside the `AgoraConnectionData` class

Answer (score 0):

Black screens usually appear when you are using the `APP_ID` of the project that is already created using agora.

Follow these steps to get rid of it:

1. Open the projects section where you can see your projects
2. Click on the CREATE button to create a new project

Note: When you will click the create button you will as below:

[image: Testing mode and secured mode]

You can see there are two options: 1 is secured and the other is testing

3. Click on the testing Mode: APP ID
   after creating this project you can now use only your `APP_ID` for the testing, now you do not need token to run the video stream or video call.

Hope this helps to solve your issue!